# Instagram icon not showing in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an application which uses `UIActivityViewController` to share a link with `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` like so:

```
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[sarray valueForKey:@"url"] description]];

NSString* someText = @"";

NSArray* dataToShare = @[shareUrl,someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
NSArray *appActivities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIActivity alloc] init], nil];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:appActivities];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
if (!completed) return;

}];
```

Except for Instagram, all options are coming up in the `UIActivityViewController`.

Can anyone help me discover where I am going wrong or is this by default?

Answer (score 1):

By default iOS doesn't have support for instagram. U might need to use 3rd party libraries.

For iOS 6 and above, you can use this UIActivity to upload images to Instagram which has the same workflow using iOS hooks but simplifies development.

Try this library

[DMActivityInstagram](https://github.com/coryalder/DMActivityInstagram)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0+**

To get the instagram app to show in the icon list, you must share an `UIImage` object in your `dataToShare` array.

I ran into a problem where my shared items contained a `URL` and an `UIImage`, and when sharing to iMessages I only wanted the `URL` to be shared and not the `UIImage`.

To solve this I made the presenting UIViewController conform to `UIActivityItemSource` protocol like so:

```
extension PresentingViewController: UIActivityItemSource {
    public func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        UIImage() // This allows instagram app to show as a choice
    }

    public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        guard let items = self.items else { return nil } // items to present
    
        switch activityType! {

        case .message, .postToTwitter, .copyToPasteboard, .mail:
            return items.first(where: { $0 is URL })

        default: // this catches the case where IG is tapped
            return items.first(where: { $0 is UIImage }) as? UIImage
    }
}
```

}

and instead of passing in an array of Activity Items that contain the object you want to share, you pass in the PresentingViewController like so:

```
// set up activity view controller
activityVC = UIActivityViewController(
   activityItems: [PresentingViewController.self],
   applicationActivities: [instaGramActivity]
)

self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram option will not be available with only text. For displaying instagram option in activity controller, you need to pass url object with text, or only url object else you can pass only image to share items which will enable instagram option for you.